# How can I share a pyqtgraph plot between different graphs?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I just started with the pyqt5 and I am working on a GUI and am having a problem sharing a plot between two different graphs. Let me explain it more clearly. Let's say you have a graph1 and a graph2:

```py
graph1 = PlotWidget()
graph2 = PlotWidget()
```

And you create two separate plots for these two graphs:

```py
plot1 = graph1.plot(name = 'plot1')
plot1.setData(x, y)
plot2 = graph2.plot(name = 'plot2')
plot2.setData(a, b)
```

You want have displayed the plot lines on these two graphs. Each displays it's own. Now you want to display the plot2 line on a graph1 window. The problem here is that when you use:

```py
graph1.plotItem.addItem(item = plot2)
```

When I do this, the plot2 does indeed appear on the graph1 but it disappears from the graph2. Removing it back from the graph1 also doesn't bring it back to graph2. I dont understand what is fundamentally wrong here. Can I show the same plot on both graphs? Why does it disappear from the graph2 when I add it to graph1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem and Explanation

As you said, the method you are using to do what you want is fundamentally wrong.

- The `plot()` method creates a `PlotDataItem`. That means when you do this: `plot1 = graph1.plot()`, you are creating an instance of `PlotDataItem` and storing it in the variable `plot1`. (Read documentation [here](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/plotdataitem.html))
- A `PlotDataItem` as its name says is an Item, an individual item. If you "add" this item to another `PlotWidget` using the `addItem()` method, you will automatically remove it from the other and add it to the destiny widget.

### A Solution

You can create another instance of `PlotDataItem`, to act as a copy of the original plot. You can add (`addItem()`) and remove (`removeItem()`) it from any widget. You want it to display the same plot, then I suggest creating a function that gets triggered when the data of the "copied plot" is changed. This way you can have two linked instances of `PlotDataItem`: one for its original widget, and the other to be added/deleted inside another widget.

Note: The `removeItem()` method don't delete the item, it just remove the item from the widget, that means you can add it again to any of the other widgets

If your data will not change then it is not necessary to create a function that links the plots. For example:

```py
plot3 = pg.PlotDataItem(name = 'Copy of plot2')
plot3.setData(a, b)
graph1.addItem(plot3) ## To add the PlotDataItem to the PlotWidget
graph1.removeItem(plot3)  ## To remove the PlotDataItem from the PlotWidget
```